# Is microwaving Styrofoam hazardous/toxic/unhealthy?

Tags: microwaves

I have heard this mentioned many times throughout life. It is also number 5 in this article's list of [Things you should never put in a microwave](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/06/13/microwave-cooking-tips_n_5488231.html). But is it really bad to microwave Styrofoam? Specifically the claim that it can give you cancer or make you sick. This [article from Harvard Health Publications](http://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/microwaving-food-in-plastic-dangerous-or-not) makes it seem like it's not as bad of an issue as people make it out to be (I could be interpreting this wrong though).

Comment: Please clarify: what is meant to happen? It's clearly *possible* to microwave anything... What is the claim?

Comment: @Sklivvz  Thanks for the comment, I'm not sure why I didn't include the claim in my question.

Comment: Maybe the question should be something like "Is microwaving Styrofoam hazardous/toxic/unhealthy ?".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/48918/can-you-put-polystyrene-in-the-microwave-oven

Comment: @DavePhD You can't close a question on one site as a duplicate of a question on another site. If the question is on topic here, it should remain open regardless of whether it has an answer on another site.

Comment: @called2voyage http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/55690/do-the-delocalised-electrons-orbit-the-nucleus

Comment: @DavePhD Physics/Chemistry is a special case, not a general rule for SE sites.

Comment: @DavePhD For reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172307/duplicate-questions-on-other-se-sites